# [Android][Node.js][Azure Easy Tables] Insert multiple entries at once

Tags: android, node.js, azure

At the moment I am using

```
      mResultTable.insert(item).get();
```

to insert one item in my table. But actually I have about ~400 items which should be uploaded at once. What is the correct way of doing it? The Android library of Azure does not provide a method for inserting multiple entries

Comment: Hi, @4ndro1d, any update, yet? Do you solve your issue now?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `middleware` in `Easy Tables` to add additional steps during the Mobile Apps table operations context. Please consider the following code snippet:

```
"use strict";

let azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');
let table = azureMobileApps.table();
let insertMiddleware = function(req,res,next){
    let t = req.azureMobile.tables('TodoItem');
    let items = req.azureMobile.item;
    let query = queries.create('TodoItem');
    if(items.length>1){
      let inserted=0;
      for(let i in items){
        t.insert(items[i]).then(function(result){
          console.log(result)
          if(result.id){
            inserted++;
          }
          if(i == items.length-1){
            res.json("finished");
          }
        })
      }
    }else{
      next();
    }
};
table.insert.use(insertMiddleware, table.operation);
// CREATE - add or overwrite the userId based on the authenticated user
table.insert(function (context) {
  return context.execute();
});
```